# BetterTouchTool 3 finger swipes stopped working

Tags: macos, bettertouchtool

I tried to configure 3 finger swipes to a new app. after I added them 3 finger swipes stopped working on all apps.

Any idea what should I do? I tried toggling all the prefpane settings restarting BTT and the computer

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yosemite 10.10.2 beta, according to the developer it's due to a bug in OS X.
Here is the tweet from the developer:

https://twitter.com/boastr_net/status/538498628500082689

You can also find a temporary fix there.